# Where can I get started with basic online functionality for a game in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, network-programming

I am creating a Boggle clone game and it works very well so far.

Right now it is only single player. I would like to make it so that other players can connect, and show up in a listbox, and then I can select that person and play a 3 min round with them.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I know a lot about VB.NET, but I have little experience with networking. In terms of a server, what would I need? I want it to be as simple as possible. All I want to send to the other person is the array of 16 letters, and I want to receive the player's score every time the timer ticks.

Comment: "My friend and I really like Boggle" - good for you! but not a real question....

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, are you honestly saying that this is not a question?

Comment: There, fixed the question :-)

Comment: Now I really fixed the question. Play nice children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Participants in networked games most commonly connect indirectly to each other via a server, but that is certainly not required. If you want to start simple, I'd suggest using TCP sockets to connect the two players. Send simple game messages over the sockets.

Test two instances of your process on the same machine first. Then, once working, test across different networks. That's when you'll come across firewall and routing issues. From there, you can configure your router to let through the traffic, or try to tunnel through SSH, or use a server.

In short: start simple with TCP sockets on the same machine. Go from there.

Comment: Signatures and taglines are discouraged on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: @Kent: Not like I should need to produce one, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/

Comment: The top-ranked answer disagrees with what you did, which is to edit only to remove my signature. Linking to a question that you asked with an answer that you accepted is hardly an authoritative source.

Comment: @Kent: Had to get your attention somehow. Now you know to stop this behavior.

Comment: Well I've gotten it to send messages accross my router, but when I use my real IP (67.68....) it doesn't work, how could I solve this.

Thanks

Comment: @unknown: Post it as a new question with new details.